# If the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ has two real roots with the same sign then...

Tags: polynomials

The constants $b,c$ are real and $c\neq 0$. If the equation $x^2+bx+c=0$ has two real roots with the same signs, then which statement is true?

a) $b > 0$

b) $c > 0$

c) $bc > 0$

d) None of the above

Drawing the function $f(x) = x^2+bx+c \ $ in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and letting $b$ and $c$ vary I find that the condition $c>0$ has to be true. How can I deduce this algebraically?

Comment: Hint: the product of the roots is ...

Comment: $-b$ is the sum of the roots. $c$ is the product of the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are our two real roots.

Take $\alpha, \beta > 0$ then:
$$(x - \alpha)(x - \beta) = x^2 + bx + c \iff x^2 + (-\alpha - \beta)x + \alpha\beta = x^2 + bx + c$$
From this we know that $b = -\alpha -\beta$ and $c = \alpha\beta$ and hence $b < 0$ and $c > 0$, so that $bc < 0$. This case alone eliminates 2 of the three 3 options that you are given.

We may conclude that $c > 0$ is our choice.

It is worth noting that when $\alpha , \beta < 0$, we will arrive at $b = -\alpha-\beta$, which would imply $b>0$ and so that $bc>0$. However, $c$ will *always* be the product of the two roots. The product of two positives being positive and likewise the product of two negatives being positive. Hence, $c>0$.

Comment: `Say α and β are our two real roots` Then $\alpha+\beta=-b\,$ and $\alpha \beta = c\,$ in all cases. `Case 2: α,β<0` The quadratic on the next line has roots $-\alpha,-\beta\,$, not $\alpha,\beta\,$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, good catch.

Comment: `hence b<0` You can't say anything about the sign of $b\,$. It can be negative when the two roots are positive, or positive when the roots are negative.

Comment: Yes, but in the case when the two roots are positive, $b$ will be negative.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_{1},x_{2}$ are the roots of the equation and such that $x_{1}x_{2} > 0$ (of the same sign), then $x^{2} + bx + c = 0$ iff $(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2}) = 0$. Note that $(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2}) = x^{2} + (-x_{1}-x_{2})x + x_{1}x_{2}$ for all $x$; so $b = -x_{1}-x_{2}$ and $c = x_{1}x_{2}$. So $c > 0$ for sure. However, if $x_{1},x_{2} > 0$ then $b < 0$; if $x_{1},x_{2} < 0$ then $b > 0$. So the sign of $b$ is indefinite, hence the sign of $bc$.